# Preparation of exam or preparation for exam. Which is correct?

Tags: prepositions

Preparation of exam or preparation for exam.
Which is correct?

Comment: exam preparation is the shortest and sweetest.

Answer (score 3):

If you are preparing to take an exam (like a test) or have an exam (such as a medical procedure), it would be 'preparation for exam.' If you are the person composing the test or preparing the elements of the procedure, it would be 'preparation of exam.'

Comment: Yes. Teachers prepare exams, students prepare for exams. There is some difference in the use of _give_ and _take_ -- in some places students do one and teachers the other, but not always the same.